# How can I remove latest word of string with PHP?

Tags: php, char, character, cpu-word

I want get first 50 characters and want end this with a word.
So I get first 50 characters with `$dis=substr($dis, 0, 50);`
And I don't know how can delete latest word.

My Text:

> You will find that the truth is often unpopular and the contest
>   between agreeable fancy and disagreeable fact is unequal.

First 50 characters:

> "You will find that the truth is often unpopular an"

While First 51 characters:

> "You will find that the truth is often unpopular and"

(First 50 characters) - (Latest word):

> "You will find that the truth is often unpopular"

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I think the OP doesn't want to end the sentence abruptly, probably the 3rd sentence is the desired result.

Comment: str_split(); and a forloop will do

Comment: forloop $dis[0] to $dis[49]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [strrpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) function to find the last empty space in the string.

```
substr($dis, 0, strrpos($dis, " "));
```

Comment: Thanks For Your Help and Good Wish For YOU.

Answer (score 0):

You can explode the shortened string by the space character, then remove the last element of the array and implode the words back into a string.

You can use `array_pop` (See: https://www.php.net/array_pop) to remove the last element of the array.

```
$dis    = substr($dis, 0, 50);
$words  = explode(' ', $dis);
$words  = array_pop($words);
$string = implode(' ', $words);
```

Comment: Thanks For your Help. But It's not work and error for 4nd line.